# Elasticsearch backfill two fields into one new field after calculations

Tags: python, elasticsearch, groovy

Question.  I have been tasked with researching how to backfill data in Elasticsearch.  So far coming up a bit empty.  The basic gist is:

Notes:  All documents are stored under daily indexes, with ~200k documents per day.

- I need to be able to reindex about 60 days worth of data.
- I need to take two fields for each doc payload.time_sec and payload.time_nanosec, take there values and do some math on them (time_sec * 10**9 + time_nanosec) and then return this as a single field into the reindexed document

I am looking at the Python API documentation with bulk helpers:
http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html

But I am wondering if this is even possible.

My thoughts were to use:
Bulk helpers to pull a scroll ID (bulk _update?), iterate over each doc id, pull that data in from the two fields for each dock, do the math, and finish the update request with the new field data.

Anyone done this?  Maybe something with a groovy script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Bulk helpers to pull a scroll ID (bulk _update?), iterate over each doc id, pull that data in from the two fields for each dock, do the math, and finish the update request with the new field data.

Basically, yes:

- use `/_search?scroll` to fetch the docs
- perform your operation
- send `/_bulk` update requests

Other options are:

- [use the `/_reindex` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-reindex.html)
  Probably not so good if you don't want to create a new index
- [use the `/_update_by_query` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query)

Both support scripting which, if I understood it correctly, wold be the perfect choice because your update does not depend on external factors so this could as well be done directly within the server.

Comment: Ive been using python to work through this issue so far, will post the code snippets in a new reply

Comment: @fastfiveoh which solution you take finally? I meet the similar problem and wonder which way is the best one.

Comment: @RobinWang I finally just wrote the script, you can see it in my repo: [link]https://github.com/fastfiveoh/python-es-reindex/blob/master/backfill_data

Answer (score 0):

Here is where I am at (roughly):

Ive been working with a Python and the bulk helpers and so far am around here:

```
doc = helpers.scan(es, query={
"query": {
"match_all": {}

},
"size":1000 
},index=INDEX, scroll='5m', raise_on_error=False)


    for x in doc:
x['_index'] = NEW_INDEX
try:
    time_sec = x['_source']['payload']['time_sec']
    time_nanosec=x['_source']['payload']['time_nanosec']
    duration = (time_sec * 10**9) + time_nanosec
except KeyError: pass

count = count + 1

x['_source']['payload']['duration'] = duration
new_index_data.append(x) 

helpers.bulk(es,new_index_data)
```

From here I am just using the bulk python helper to insert into a new index.  However I will experiment changing and testing with bulk update to an existing index.

This look like a right approach?

Comment: also the reason I am moving to a new index, then will delete the old index and point an alias to the new index is to take a new mapping template.

Comment: Sounds even more appropriate to make use of the `_reindex` API

Comment: Ya I didnt think reindex would be good.  I am checking data integrity going back 3 months, backfilling about 6 - 8 new fields.